# Java: Equivalent of Python's range(int, int)?

Tags: java

Does Java have an equivalent to Python's `range(int, int)` method?

Comment: Do you mean a Python 2.x range which returns a list, or a Python 3.x range which returns an iterator (equivalent to the 2.x xrange)?  The former is relatively simple to implement as others have done below, but the iterator version is a bit more tricky.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570091/for-loop-like-python-range-function/31867991#31867991

Comment: For a range of any `Comparable` s see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245738/3992939) answer

Comment: For a range with stepping see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052429/python-like-range-with-stepping-in-pure-java/58058221)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) also provides something similar to Python's `range`:

```
Range.closed(1, 5).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers());
```

You can also implement a fairly simple iterator to do the same sort of thing using Guava's AbstractIterator:

```
return new AbstractIterator<Integer>() {
  int next = getStart();

  @Override protected Integer computeNext() {
    if (isBeyondEnd(next)) {
      return endOfData();
    }
    Integer result = next;
    next = next + getStep();
    return result;
  }
};
```

Comment: I wish I had seen this before I implemented my own generic range.  It's nice but still another reminder of how clunky Java can be compared to more functional languages.

Comment: `Range#asSet` is seems to have become deprecated. You now need to do this: `ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(low, high), DiscreteDomain.integers())`

Comment: what library to i need to import to use this?

Comment: From Java 8, IntStream and LongStream have methods range and rangeClosed.

Answer (score 257):

Old question, new answer (for Java 8)

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
```

or with method references:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What package?  how do I import it?

Comment: @Justin That is java 8 language feature.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html

Comment: the first example could just be:
 `Intstream.range(0,10).forEach( n -> System.out.println(n)); `

Answer (score 17):

I'm working on a little Java utils library called [Jools](https://github.com/Nurdok/Jools), and it contains a class `Range` which provides the functionality you need (there's a downloadable JAR).
Constructors are either `Range(int stop)`, `Range(int start, int stop)`, or `Range(int start, int stop, int step)` (similiar to a for loop) and you can either iterate through it, which used lazy evaluation, or you can use its `toList()` method to explicitly get the range list.

```
for (int i : new Range(10)) {...} // i = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

for (int i : new Range(4,10)) {...} // i = 4,5,6,7,8,9

for (int i : new Range(0,10,2)) {...} // i = 0,2,4,6,8

Range range = new Range(0,10,2);
range.toList(); // [0,2,4,6,8]
```

Answer (score 16):

Since Guava 15.0, [Range.asSet()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#asSet%28com.google.common.collect.DiscreteDomain%29) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in version 16.  Use the following instead:

```
ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, 5), DiscreteDomain.integers());
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following code snippet in order to get a range set of integers:

```
    Set<Integer> iset = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).boxed().collect
            (Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 15):

```
public int[] range(int start, int stop)
{
   int[] result = new int[stop-start];

   for(int i=0;i<stop-start;i++)
      result[i] = start+i;

   return result;
}
```

Forgive any syntax or style errors; I normally program in C#.

Comment: given that Vivien Barousse beat you to an answer, why don't you delete yours to avoid any dup. Unless you really plan to nicely flesh it out of course.

Comment: They're similar; I think mine's a little more readable. His use of "length" is misleading, and I don't think his meets the Python spec (he includes the upper bound, which http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/rangeFunction.html says doesn't happen in Python). If you think one's a dupe, I believe you have sufficient reputation to deal with it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

```
public int[] range(int start, int length) {
    int[] range = new int[length - start + 1];
    for (int i = start; i <= length; i++) {
        range[i - start] = i;
    }
    return range;
}
```

(Long answer just to say "No")

Comment: Also, see that "range" in python 3 and the preferred "xrange" in Python 2 return a "live" object that does not use up memory for each item it contains. That would be even bigger to implement in Java.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 9 - [`IntStream::iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate(int,java.util.function.IntPredicate,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator))

Since Java 9 you can use `IntStream::iterate` and you can even customize the step. For example if you want `int` array :

```
public static int[] getInRange(final int min, final int max, final int step) {
    return IntStream.iterate(min, i -> i < max, i -> i + step)
            .toArray();
}
```

or `List` :

```
public static List<Integer> getInRange(final int min, final int max, final int step) {
    return IntStream.iterate(min, i -> i < max, i -> i + step)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then use it :

```
int[] range = getInRange(0, 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```java
IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

Comment: It would help if you explained *how* this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Groovy's nifty [Range class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections#Collections-Ranges) can be used from Java, though it's certainly not as groovy.

Answer (score 2):

The "Functional Java" library allows to program in such a way to a limited degree, it has a range() method creating an fj.data.Array instance.

See:

- http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Array.html#range%28int,%20int%29

Similarly the "Totally Lazy" library offers a lazy range method:
http://code.google.com/p/totallylazy/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but if you are looking for a solution that returns an object stream and don't want to or can't use any additional dependencies:

```
Stream.iterate(start, n -> n + 1).limit(stop);
```

**start** - inclusive
**stop** - exclusive

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to use it like you would in a Python loop, Java loops nicely with the for statement, which renders this structure unnecessary for that purpose.

Comment: You don't usually use it for a loop in python either. There's almost always a cleaner way to iterate.

Comment: Well, range is usually used in a for loop.  But for loops are often used without range.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8

```
private static int[] range(int start, int stop, int step) {
    int[] result = new int[(stop-start)%step == 0 ? (stop-start)/step : (stop-start)/step+1];
    int count = 0;
    Function<Integer, Boolean> condition = step > 0 ? (x) -> x < stop : (x) -> x > stop;
    for (int i = start; condition.apply(i); i += step) {
        result[count] = i;
        count++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65020704/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.