# How can I represent a range in Java?

Tags: java

Let's say an integer should be within the range: `[0...2147483647]`

I want to check whether an integer variable falls within this range. I know it can be accomplished by a simple if-else statement, but is there a more efficient way to check whether it's within the range?

I'd rather not do this:

```
if (foo >= 0 && foo <= 2147483647) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: If you’re asking for runtime efficiency (performance), I’m afraid that your `if` statement wins. I agree, though, that this observation shouldn’t drive your decision. For 99 % of applications, maintenance efficiency will be more important.

Comment: @OleV.V. I’d even simplify it to `if(foo >= 0) …`, as there’s no need to check whether an `int` is `<=Integer.MAX_VALUE` at all. But I doubt that the questioner will ever read these comments, as after five years of absence, coming back is quiet unlikely.

Comment: @OleV.V., Care has to be taken in how often and in what way this is called.  Pipelining becomes 100% squashed on conditionals.  If you can enforce a clamped range through some other "solid state" mathematical wizardry, then you'll be better off.

Answer (score 69):

Apache Commons Lang has a [`Range` class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html) for doing arbitrary ranges.

```
Range<Integer> test = Range.between(1, 3);
System.out.println(test.contains(2));
System.out.println(test.contains(4));
```

[Guava `Range`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) has similar API.

If you are just wanting to check if a number fits into a long value or an int value, you could try using it through `BigDecimal`. There are methods for `longValueExact` and `intValueExact` that throw exceptions if the value is too big for those precisions.

Comment: Yes, but how do you think `.contains(...)` is implemented? ;) (With an if/else for sure :)

Comment: Do you know off hand if it is able to handle the outside-edges.     (int example)  something like <=-5  OR  something like   >= 12  ?

Comment: Answer my own question.  "Yes" is the answer.  See : Range.atMost and Range.atLeast.  https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html

Comment: The problem with this `Range` is that it seems to be missing something akin to an `addWrap()` and `subtractWrap()` concepts, both of which are very useful when you need to dec/subtracting downward a value below minimum to wrap to max and similar for inc/adding a value to wrap when past max.  You could even use the `%` if required and allow floating point.  These are very easy to implement on your own, but they really should at least be `Math` methods IMO to take advantage of any native-level atomic operations that may be present.

Answer (score 33):

You could create a class to represent this

```
public class Range
{
    private int low;
    private int high;

    public Range(int low, int high){
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
    }

    public boolean contains(int number){
        return (number >= low && number <= high);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Range range = new Range(0, 2147483647);

if (range.contains(foo)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I now see you were trying to avoid the if. I thought you just didn't like the comparison syntax in the if... oh well.

Comment: With this implementation, you cannot represent an empty range (assuming `low <= high`).  Either the interval must be half-open `[low, high)` or else use an `extent` instead of `high`.

Answer (score 22):

I know this is quite an old question, but with Java 8's Streams you can get a range of `int`s like this:

```
// gives an IntStream of integers from 0 through Integer.MAX_VALUE
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
if (IntStream.rangeClosed(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE).matchAny(n -> n == A)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else 
}
```

Comment: This is a very slow solution. You are doing 2 billion comparisons rather than 2.

Comment: @Michael *up to* 2 billion comparisons, but only `A` in the best case. On the other hand, you need only *one* actual comparison, `A >= 0` here.

Answer (score 12):

You could use `java.time.temporal.ValueRange` which accepts `long` and would also work with `int`:

```
int a = 2147;

//Use java 8 java.time.temporal.ValueRange. The range defined
//is inclusive of both min and max 
ValueRange range = ValueRange.of(0, 2147483647);

if(range.isValidValue(a)) {
    System.out.println("in range");
}else {
    System.out.println("not in range");
}
```

Comment: I like this, unfortunately it's in the Time package but is usable in many other cases.

Answer (score 8):

If you are checking against a lot of intervals, I suggest using an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: Is there a known Java library that implements an interval tree?

Answer (score 5):

You will have an if-check no matter how efficient you try to optimize this not-so-intensive computation :) You can subtract the upper bound from the number and if it's positive you know you are out of range. You can perhaps perform some boolean bit-shift logic to figure it out and you can even use Fermat's theorem if you want (kidding :) But the point is "why" do you need to optimize this comparison? What's the purpose?

Comment: I'm with the OP - this kind of procedural check has always felt awkward. I prefer declarative contracts when available, even if the former eventually reduces to the latter.

Comment: I need to optimize because I find it much slower when let's say A is a really big number. And what if I choose to expand and do other checks within that if..else statement? >_<

Comment: You must be kidding -- slow? As in you have measured it to perform badly?

Comment: No... >_< I meant, I have OTHER checks within that if else statement, not just that... >_< That's why I'm thinking that if there was another way.

Answer (score 1):

For a range of `Comparable` I use the following :

```
public class Range<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    /**
     * Include start, end in {@link Range}
     */
    public enum Inclusive {START,END,BOTH,NONE }

    /**
     * {@link Range} start and end values
     */
    private T start, end;
    private Inclusive inclusive;

    /**
     * Create a range with {@link Inclusive#START}
     * @param start
     *<br/> Not null safe
     * @param end
     *<br/> Not null safe
     */
    public Range(T start, T end) {  this(start, end, null); }

    /**
     * @param start
     *<br/> Not null safe
     * @param end
     *<br/> Not null safe
     *@param inclusive
     *<br/>If null {@link Inclusive#START} used
     */
    public Range(T start, T end, Inclusive inclusive) {

        if((start == null) || (end == null)) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Invalid null start / end value");
        }
        setInclusive(inclusive);

        if( isBigger(start, end) ) {
            this.start = end;   this.end   = start;
        }else {
            this.start = start;  this.end   = end;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method
     */
    public boolean isBigger(T t1, T t2) { return t1.compareTo(t2) > 0; }

    /**
     * Convenience method
     */
    public boolean isSmaller(T t1, T t2) { return t1.compareTo(t2) < 0; }

    /**
     * Check if this {@link Range} contains t
     *@param t
     *<br/>Not null safe
     *@return
     *false for any value of t, if this.start equals this.end
     */
    public boolean contains(T t) { return contains(t, inclusive); }

    /**
     * Check if this {@link Range} contains t
     *@param t
     *<br/>Not null safe
     *@param inclusive
     *<br/>If null {@link Range#inclusive} used
     *@return
     *false for any value of t, if this.start equals this.end
     */
    public boolean contains(T t, Inclusive inclusive) {

        if(t == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Invalid null value");
        }

        inclusive = (inclusive == null) ? this.inclusive : inclusive;

        switch (inclusive) {
            case NONE:
                return ( isBigger(t, start) && isSmaller(t, end) );
            case BOTH:
                return ( ! isBigger(start, t)  && ! isBigger(t, end) ) ;
            case START: default:
                return ( ! isBigger(start, t)  &&  isBigger(end, t) ) ;
            case END:
                return ( isBigger(t, start)  &&  ! isBigger(t, end) ) ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if this {@link Range} contains other range
     * @return
     * false for any value of range, if this.start equals this.end
     */
    public boolean contains(Range<T> range) {
        return contains(range.start) && contains(range.end);
    }

    /**
     * Check if this {@link Range} intersects with other range
     * @return
     * false for any value of range, if this.start equals this.end
     */
    public boolean intersects(Range<T> range) {
        return contains(range.start) || contains(range.end);
    }

    /**
    * Get {@link #start}
    */
    public T getStart() { return start; }

    /**
    * Set {@link #start}
    * <br/>Not null safe
    * <br/>If start > end they are switched
    */
    public Range<T> setStart(T start) {

        if(start.compareTo(end)>0) {
            this.start = end;
            this.end  = start;
        }else {
            this.start = start;
        }
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * Get {@link #end}
    */
    public T getEnd() {  return end;  }

    /**
    * Set {@link #end}
    * <br/>Not null safe
    *  <br/>If start > end they are switched
    */
    public  Range<T> setEnd(T end) {

        if(start.compareTo(end)>0) {
            this.end  = start;
            this.start = end;
        }else {
            this.end = end;
        }
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * Get {@link #inclusive}
    */
    public Inclusive getInclusive() { return inclusive; }

    /**
    * Set {@link #inclusive}
    * @param inclusive
    *<br/>If null {@link Inclusive#START} used
    */
    public  Range<T> setInclusive(Inclusive inclusive) {

        this.inclusive = (inclusive == null) ? Inclusive.START : inclusive;
        return this;
    }
}
```

(This is a somewhat shorted version. The full code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/c0derepo/range) )

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Soft{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] nums=range(9, 12);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }
    static int[] range(int low, int high){
        int[] a=new int[high-low];
        for(int i=0,j=low;i<high-low;i++,j++){
            a[i]=j;
        }
        return a;

    }
}
```

My code is similar to Python`s range :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring, you can rely on org.springframework.data.domain that is quite complete including **bound and unbound** ranges.