# Interval lock Implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, locking, wait

I am looking for an implementation of interval lock. Given an interval `(x, y)`, a thread can acquire the lock if no-one else is acquiring any interval that contains point `p` where `x <= p <= y`.

My current idea is maintaining an array of existing granted intervals `(x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xn, yn)` where `x1 < y1 < x2 < y2 < ... < xn < yn` and checks to see if `(x, y)` overlaps with any of those intervals.

The search takes `O(logn)` time which makes me happy. However, when the search returns that there is some overlaps, the `lock` function needs to somehow retry efficiently until it can acquire the lock when others release their interval locks. Busy-waiting or sleep seems not a good idea.

Is there a way to implement the retry efficiently?

Comment: How about listening to changes in the `array of existing granted intervals` and retry only when it has changed ?

Comment: That would be a good idea. I will come up with a design for that...

Comment: Did you find the right design ?

Comment: Yes, I have two designs: one for exclusive lock, and another that allows Read lock and Write lock. I implemented them both and am still testing them. I will put the github links here soon.

Answer (score 3):

As @c0der suggested I've made an implementation that simply tracks the locked intervals.

My code implies a `Range` class that ...

- is immutable
- has a lower and upper bound (extending to unbounded ranges shouldn't be too hard)
- properly implements `equals()` and `hashCode()`

The `RangeLock` class currently only implements a blocking lock method. Unlocking is done through a returned `Unlocker` instance. This is to avoid threads not having acquired the lock, being able to unlock a given `Range`.

```
public class RangeLock<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    private final SortedSet<Range<T>> locked = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Range::lower));
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public Unlocker lock(Range<T> range) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (!available(range)) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            locked.add(range);
            return () -> {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    locked.remove(range);
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private boolean available(Range<T> range) {
        SortedSet<Range<T>> tailSet = locked.tailSet(range);
        SortedSet<Range<T>> headSet = locked.headSet(range);
        return (tailSet.isEmpty() || !tailSet.first().overlaps(range)) && (headSet.isEmpty() || !headSet.last().overlaps(range));
    }

    public interface Unlocker {
        void unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can probably make this a little easier with Guava's [range support](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained).

Comment: @shmosel Other than use their Range class?

Comment: They also have a [`RangeSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html).

Comment: @shmosel I know, it just doesn't help me any better than a TreeSet already does

Comment: Not fundamentally, but it does simplify some of the logic. You can replace `available(range)` with `!locked.intersects(range)`.

Comment: @shmosel not sure if the coalescing of rangeset is desirable, and the added value is still marginal.

Comment: What could be the problem with coalescing ranges?

Comment: Well, this code does not need it, and I'd have to check and test it to make sure it doesn't cause any problems. Can't think of anything off hand.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is essentially about an efficient way to have a thread wait and retry.
How about listening to changes in the

> array of existing granted intervals

and retry only when it has changed ?
The following should not be considered a proper implementation (my experience with thread is very limited), but a demonstration of the proposed mechanism:

***Ranges.java*** and ***Range.java***

```
//represents all ranges
//see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7721388/3992939
public class Ranges {

    private List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
    private PropertyChangeSupport rangeChangedProperty = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public Range getRange(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd) {

        if(contains(rangeStart) || contains(rangeEnd)) {
            return null;
        }
        Range range = new Range(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
        range.addListener( (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                rangeChangedProperty.firePropertyChange("Range", "-" , "changed");
            }
        );
        ranges.add(range);
        return range;
    }

    private boolean contains(int number){
        for(Range range : ranges) {
            if(range.contains(number)) {return true;}
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean removeRange(Range range) {

        boolean isContains = ranges.remove(range);
        rangeChangedProperty.firePropertyChange("Range", "-" , "removed");
        return isContains;
    }

    /**
     * Listen to {@link #rangeChangedProperty}. Fires whenever a range changes
     * or removed.
     * <br/>A client and a listener and when it fires, notify all threads.
     */
    public void addChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        rangeChangedProperty.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    //represents a single range
    //It is muttable 
    //can be implemented using ValueRange (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40716042/3992939)
    class Range{

        private SimpleIntegerProperty low = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private SimpleIntegerProperty high = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private SimpleObjectProperty<int[]> rangeProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        private Range(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd){

            low.set(rangeStart) ; high.set(rangeEnd);
            updateRange();
            low.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { updateRange(); });
            high.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { updateRange(); });
        }

        /**
         * Listen to {@link #rangeProperty} that changes whenever the range changes
         */
        void addListener(ChangeListener<int[]> listener) {
            rangeProperty.addListener(listener);
        }

        private void updateRange() {rangeProperty.set(new int[] {low.get(), high.get()});}

        public int getRangeStart() { return low.get(); }

        public void setRangeStart(int rangeStart) { low.set(rangeStart);}

        public int getRangeEnd() {return high.get();}

        public void setRangeEnd(int rangeEnd) { high.set(rangeEnd);}

        public boolean contains(int number){
            int min = Math.min(low.get(), high.get());
            int max = Math.max(low.get(), high.get());
            return ((number >= min) && (number <= max));
        }
    }
}
```

***GetRange.java***

```
//used to simulate a thread trying to get a range 
public class GetRange implements Runnable{

    private Ranges ranges;
    private int low, high;
    private String id;

    GetRange(Ranges ranges, int low, int high, String id) {
        this.ranges = ranges;
        this.low = low; this.high = high; this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (ranges) {
            while(ranges.getRange(low,high) == null) {
                System.out.println("Tread "+ id + " is waiting");
                try {
                    ranges.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Tread "+ id + " got range. All done");
    }
}
```

Test is with :

```
//test
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Ranges ranges = new Ranges();
    ranges.addChangeListener( (evt) -> {
        synchronized (ranges) {
            ranges.notifyAll();
            System.out.println(evt.getPropertyName() + " "+ evt.getNewValue());
        }
    });

    Range range1 = ranges.getRange(10,15);
    Range range2 = ranges.getRange(20,25);

    new Thread(new GetRange(ranges, 10, 12, "A")).start();
    new Thread(new GetRange(ranges, 21, 28, "B")).start();
    new Thread(new GetRange(ranges, 10, 12, "C")).start();

    Thread.sleep(50);
    System.out.println("-- Changing end of range 1. Threads notifyied and keep waiting -----");
    range1.setRangeEnd(16);   //no thread effected
    Thread.sleep(50);
    System.out.println("-- Changing start of range 1. Threads notifyied and A or C get range -----");
    range1.setRangeStart(13); //effects thread A or C
    Thread.sleep(50);
    System.out.println("-- Removing range 2. Threads notifyied and B get range -----");
    ranges.removeRange(range2);//effects thread B
    Thread.sleep(50);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Output:

> Tread A is waiting 
>  Tread C is waiting 
> Tread B is waiting 
>   -- Changing end of range 1. Threads notifyied and keep waiting -----
>   Range changed 
>   Tread B is waiting 
>   Tread C is waiting 
>  
>   Tread A is waiting 
>  
>   -- Changing start of range 1. Threads notifyied and A or C get range ----- 
> Range changed Tread A got range. All done 
>  
>   Thread C is waiting
>  
>   Tread B is waiting 
>  
>   -- Removing range 2. Threads notifyied and B get range ----- 
>   Range removed 
>  
>   Tread B got range. All done 
>  
>   Tread C is waiting

Comment: No, but it's nice. Up voted it. I thought about using observable values, to avoid the use of loops like `while (!available(range)) `. It is a shame that the OP has disappeared and does not participate in this discussion.

Comment: If you could explain that idea so I understand how it's supposed to work, I might have a go at that :) But with `wait()` you need a loop.

Comment: I was thinking about unlocking activated by an event, not a loop. To demonstrate it think about an observable array which contains a locked range. You could unlock the waiting threads when this array changes.

Comment: Let's say ranges [1-4] and [7-11] are locked, and a third thread is blocked because tries to lock [3- 8], what would your array look like?

Comment: I guess each range should be represented bu an array. If ranges are continuous it holding the 2 ends is enough : {1,4}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156854/discussion-between-bowmore-and-c0der).

Answer (score 0):

Guava's [`Striped` locks](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) may be of interest to you.

If you have a function `int key(int p)` which returns the index `i` of the interval `[x_i,y_i]` which `p` belongs to, you could probably use a `Striped` lock to achieve your goal.

For instance, if we had as interval bounds the points `x_1`, `x_2`, ... `x_n` such that `x_i < x_(i+1)` and `x_(i+1) - x_i` remains constant over all `i` from `1` to `n`, we could use something like `key(p) = p -> (p - x_1) / n`.

However, based on the notation you chose, this assumption may not hold and the function `key` be not as straightforward - but hopefully a lock striping solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation for IntervalLock that supports Read and Write locks. Reads may acquire locks that have ranges overlapped, while a write must wait if its range overlaps with any other read or write. The basic idea is to use an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) to store the ranges. At a given time, each range may hold a write lock or multiple read locks. Insertion and deletion ranges from the tree must done carefully to prevent any race conditions. The code uses an implementation of interval tree from [here](https://github.com/masonmlai/interval-tree).

**SemaphoreInterval.java**

```
package intervallock;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import datastructures.Interval;

public class SemaphoreInterval implements Interval {
    private ArrayList<Semaphore> semaphores;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int mode;

    public SemaphoreInterval(int start, int end, int mode) {
        this.semaphores = new ArrayList<>(1);
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public int getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public ArrayList<Semaphore> getSemaphores() {
        return semaphores;
    }

    @Override
    public int start() {
        return start;
    }

    @Override
    public int end() {
        return end+1;
    }
}
```

**IntervalLock.java**

```
package intervallock;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import datastructures.IntervalTree;

/**
 * An implementation of Interval Lock
 * 
 * @author Hieu
 *
 */
public class IntervalLock {
    public IntervalTree<SemaphoreInterval> tree;
    private Semaphore treeLock;
    private int maxPermits;

    public static final int READ = 0;
    public static final int WRITE = 1;

    public IntervalLock(int maxPermits) {
        tree = new IntervalTree<>();
        treeLock = new Semaphore(1);
        this.maxPermits = maxPermits;
    }

    /**
     * Acquire a lock on range [start, end] with the specified mode.
     * @param start The start of the interval
     * @param end   The end of the interval
     * @param mode  The mode, either IntervalLock.READ or IntervalLock.WRITE.
     * @return The SemaphoreInterval instance.
     */
    public SemaphoreInterval acquire(int start, int end, int mode) {
        SemaphoreInterval si = new SemaphoreInterval(start, end, mode);
        Set<Semaphore> semaphores = new HashSet<>();

        try {
            treeLock.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Iterator<SemaphoreInterval> overlappers = tree.overlappers(si);
        while (overlappers.hasNext()) {
            SemaphoreInterval i = overlappers.next();
            if (i == null) {
                System.out.println("Error: Getting a null interval");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            if (i.compareTo(si) == 0)
                continue;

            switch (i.getMode()) {
            case READ:
                if (mode == WRITE) 
                    semaphores.addAll(i.getSemaphores());
                break;
            case WRITE:
                semaphores.addAll(i.getSemaphores());
                break;
            }
        }

        SemaphoreInterval result = tree.insert(si);
        if (result != null)
            si = result;
        si.getSemaphores().add(new Semaphore(0));
        treeLock.release();

        for (Semaphore s: semaphores) {
            try {
                s.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

        return si;
    }

    /**
     * Release the range lock hold on specified SemaphoreInterval.
     * @param si The semaphore interval returned by the acquire().
     */
    public void release(SemaphoreInterval si) {
        try {
            treeLock.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        if (si.getSemaphores() == null || si.getSemaphores().size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Empty array of semaphores");
            treeLock.release();
            return;
        }
        Semaphore sm = si.getSemaphores().remove(0);
        if (si.getSemaphores().size() == 0) {
            boolean success = tree.delete(si);
            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Error: Cannot remove an interval.");
                treeLock.release();
                return;
            }
        }
        treeLock.release();
        sm.release(maxPermits);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// init the lock with the max permits per semaphore (should be the max number of threads)
public static final IntervalLock lock = new IntervalLock(1000);

// ...

// acquire the lock on range [a, b] (inclusive), with mode (either IntervalLock.READ or IntervalLock.WRITE)
// it returns a SemaphoreInterval instance
SemaphoreInterval si = lock.acquire(a, b, mode);

// ...

// release the acquired lock
lock.release(si);
```

Comment: The implementation uses `semaphore.release(maxPermits)` to release the semaphore so that other threads that are acquiring it can proceed. The code may break if the number of threads acquiring this semaphore is greater than `maxPermits`, which may cause one thread to wait forever. Any idea to remove this dependency?