# how to avoid multiple if statements

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement

I have next code:

```
private static final List<String> VALUES =
  ImmutableList.of("15", "545", "856", "5", "4558"); 

public int getAmountOfUnits(String value, int duration) {

    if (VALUES.contains(value)) {

        if (duration >= 1 && duration <= 7) 
            return 0;

        if (duration >= 8 && duration <= 82) {
            return getUnitAmount(duration, 22, 15, 1);
        }

        if (duration >= 83 && duration <= 90) 
            return 7;

        if (duration >= 91) {
            return getUnitAmount(duration, 114, 24, 7);
        }
    }


    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("3") && duration >= 0) {
        return getUnitAmount(duration, 15, 16, 1);
    }

    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("4") && duration >= 0) {
        return getUnitAmount(duration, 59, 60, 0);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

List item

```
private int getUnitAmount(int input, int startRange, int increment, int startUnit) {
  while (startRange < input) {
    startUnit++;
    startRange += increment;
  }
  return startUnit;
}
```

How I can avoid this multile line if statments?

Comment: This Kind of questions is better asked at [codereview.SE]. Because it is about runnig code

Comment: I'd use guava's `RangeMap` here

Comment: Read pls this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721332/how-can-i-represent-a-range-in-java

Comment: You can also simplify your getUnit method, it's simply a : `startUnit + (input-startRange)/increment;`

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is really little that you can spare, as the different conditions involve different code anyway. You can reorganize the four tests on duration as a dichotomic search, but the gain is quite marginal...

Answer (score 0):

You will need those `if` conditions, however you can reduce some checks and produce a more compact code. Performance difference though is very negligible.

```
public int getAmountOfUnits(String value, int duration) {
    if(duration < 0) return 1; // here you can return whatever you intend to do.
    if (VALUES.contains(value)) {    
        if (duration <= 7){ 
            return 0;
        }else if (duration <= 82) {
            return getUnitAmount(duration, 22, 15, 1);
        }else if (duration <= 90){ 
            return 7;
        }else{
            return getUnitAmount(duration, 114, 24, 7);
        }
    }



        if(value.equals("3")){
            return getUnitAmount(duration, 15, 16, 1);
        }else if(value.equals("4")){
            return getUnitAmount(duration, 59, 60, 0);
        }


    return 1;
}
```