# How can I manage items with overlapping ranges, where based on a value I get the matching items

Tags: java, range

Say I have the following items (unsorted):

```
A, with A.amount = 10
B, with B.amount = 100
C, with C.amount = 50
D, with D.amount = 50
```

Now for every unique amount boundary *AB* in items, find the items whose range include the value and calculate cumulative bracket. So:

```
AB=10 results in { A, B, C, D } -> cumulative bracket 210
AB=50 results in { B, C, D } -> cumulative bracket 200
AB=100 results in { B } -> cumulative bracket 100
```

It would be used like so:

```
for (int AB : collectAmountBoundaries(items)) {
   Collection<Item> itemsInBracket = findItemsForAB(items, AB);
   // execute logic, calculations etc with cumulative bracket value for AB
}
```

Now I can code all this using vanilla Java, by first manually transforming the collection of items into a map of *AB→cumulativeBracketValue* or something. However, since I'm working with ranges and overlap-logic I feel somehow a clean solution involving [NavigableMap](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-navigablemap-and-treemap-tutorial-and-examples), [Range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7721439/441662) logic or something clever should be possible (it feels like a common pattern). Or perhaps using streams to do a *collect groupingBy*?

I'm not seeing it right now. Any ideas on how to tackle this cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

I think, doing a simple filter and then adding the filtered result to a List and amount to a total is sufficient.

```
static ListAndCumalativeAmount getCR(List<Item> items, double amount) {

    ListAndCumalativeAmount result = new ListAndCumalativeAmount();

    items.stream().filter(item -> item.amount >= amount).forEach((i) -> {
        result.getItems().add(i.name);
        result.add(i.amount);
    });

    return result;
}

static class ListAndCumalativeAmount {

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private Double amount = new Double(0.0);

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void add(double value) {
        amount = amount + value;
    }


    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Mayb it can be this simple, but you're missing some steps here!

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it with streams and groupingBy:

```
Map<Integer, SimpleEntry<List<Item>, Double>> groupedByBracketBoundary = items.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(o -> o.getAmount())).entrySet().stream()
        // map map-values to map-entries of original value and sum, keeping key the same
        .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getValue(), 
            e.getValue().stream()
                .map(o -> o.getAmount())
                .reduce(0d, (amount1, amount2) -> amount1 + amount2))));

LinkedHashSet<Integer> sortedUniqueAmountBoundaries = internalList.stream()
        .map(o -> o.getAmount())
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

for (int ab : sortedUniqueAmountBoundaries) {
    List<Item> itemsInBracket = groupedByBracketBoundary.get(ab).getKey();
    double cumulativeAmountForBracket = groupedByBracketBoundary.get(ab).getValue();
    // execute logic, calculations etc with cumulative bracket value for AB
}
```

Somehow this feels succinct and verbose at the same time, it's rather dense. Isn't there a JDK api or 3rd party library that does this kind of thing?