# Java: Array of first n integers

Tags: java, arrays

Any shortcut to create a Java array of the first n integers without doing an explicit loop?
In R, it would be

```
intArray = c(1:n)
```

(and the resulting vector would be 1,2,...,n).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790142/java-equivalent-of-pythons-rangeint-int.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(float[], int, int)

Comment: You said "array" and "vector", which are 2 different things in Java and the simplest way to do this is different for each of those.  Do you know which you want?

Answer (score 16):

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you could do:

```
int[] arr = IntStream.range(1, n).toArray();
```

This will create an array containing the integers from `[0, n)`. You can use [`rangeClosed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) if you want to include `n` in the resulting array.

If you want to specify a step, you could [`iterate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) and then [`limit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#limit-long-) the stream to take the first `n` elements you want.

```
int[] arr = IntStream.iterate(0, i ->i + 2).limit(10).toArray(); //[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Otherwise I guess the simplest way to do is to use a loop and fill the array. You can create a helper method if you want.

```
static int[] fillArray(int from, int to, int step){
    if(to < from || step <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("to < from or step <= 0");

    int[] array = new int[(to-from)/step+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = from;
        from += step;
    }
    return array;
}
...
int[] arr3 = fillArray(0, 10, 3); //[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

You can adapt this method as your needs to go per example from an upperbound to a lowerbound with a negative step.