# How to loop for a fixed number of iterations?

Tags: c, for-loop

Is there any way of making a `for` loop iterate a fixed number of times, even though the right side of the interval might be increasing ?
I want to do this  without declaring an additional variable to use as a copy of the initial `inc`.
For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < inc; i++)
{
  if (condition) 
  {
     inc++;
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure that if `inc` increases, the for will execute more than `inc - 1` times. How can I iterate exactly `inc` times, without using a copy of `inc` ?

Comment: You aren't looping a fixed number of iterations so you shouldn't use a for loop, should be a while. I'd tear you a new one in code review even if you got this to work somehow....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = inc; i > 0; i--) {
    if (condition) {
        inc++;
    }
}
```

This would work since you only assign inc once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are possibly looking for a 'range', you don't say what language its for but in python something like:

```
 inc = 2
 for i in range[0:10]:
      if i > inc:
           inc=inc+1
      print inc
```

Comment: for java see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790142/java-equivalent-of-pythons-rangeint-int