# Array and for loops

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, increment

lets say we have the following pseudo-code:

`count = 0 
 for i in range(0,N):
 if a[i] == 0:
   count+= 1`

Why would you want to go from 0 to N? Let`s say the array has 10 entries. If you were to go from 0 to 10 you would compare 11 numbers to 0. Would it not be correct to change the range to

```
for i in range(0,N-1):
```

Comment: `range(0,N)` will generate integers from 0 up to N-1. That is how `range` in python works. Moreover, you can just use `range(N)` as the default start is from 0 unless you want to start from some other number

Comment: N in not included, --> [0,N), will give your rnage from [0,N-1]

Comment: What the [official documentation on `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) states, goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
N = len (a)
count = 0 
for i in range(0,N):
    if a[i] != -1:
        print(a[i])
        count+= 1
```

Try experimenting by printing out the contents of each accessed element from within your loop. You might be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3+ range(0, N) means it will iterate from 0 to N-1. In a programming language like java, the programmer needs to take care of n-1 factor while in python it has been taken care of python.

Comment: `In a programming language like java, the programmer needs to take care of n-1 factor while in python it has been taken care of python` This is using a foreach loop, which also exists in "programming languages like java" (and c++11, and C#, and others). The only difference here, python has native `range()` function. [Java also has something similar now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22903362/572670).